How to test POST request form submission with redirect in @SpringBootTest
I am thoroughly learning Spring Boot, I have come towards the end and this seems to be the last sticking point.
I feel what I am not getting is one of those things that is so simple and straight forward, It's not even explained.
Anyway, I have a simple CRUD demo, where I have a form that is posted to create an entity that is hard coded, once I submit the form, there is a redirect to the page that shows the new entity created.
It works perfectly in the web browser tested many times, and in postman, but for some reason when I am doing @WebMvcTest and @SpringBootTest, I get the correct 302 response status, but THERE IS NO RESPONSE BODY from the redirect response.
I did read this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555607/21505152
Even the main docs lack any info:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/spring-mvc-test-framework/vs-end-to-end-integration-tests.html
Which basically shows that MockMvc might not be able to test such scenarios, if so, what is the alternative ?
Do I even need to test this ?
What is going on ? As everything is working perfectly in the browser
Here is the code:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dummy-entities")
public class DummyEntityController {

    private DummyEntityDao dao;

    public DummyEntityController(DummyEntityDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public String getAll(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("mainHeading", "Dummy Entities");
        model.addAttribute("dummyEntities", dao.getDummyEntities());
        return "dummyentities/dummy-entities";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getById(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        try {
            model.addAttribute("dummyEntity", dao.getDummyEntityById(id));
            return "dummyentities/dummy-entity";
        }catch (DummyEntityNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String getAddDummyEntityView() {
        return "dummyentities/add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addDummyEntity(@ModelAttribute DummyEntity dummyEntity) {
        DummyEntity newDummyEntity = dao.createDummyEntity(dummyEntity);
        return "redirect:/dummy-entities/" + newDummyEntity.getId();
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String getEditDummyEntityView(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        try {
            DummyEntity dummyEntity = dao.getDummyEntityById(id);
            model.addAttribute("dummyEntity", dummyEntity);
            return "dummyentities/edit";
        }catch (DummyEntityNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @PostMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editDummyEntity(@ModelAttribute DummyEntity dummyEntity) {
        try {
            dao.updateDummyEntityById(dummyEntity);
        }catch (DummyEntityWriteException e) {

        }

        return "redirect:/dummy-entities/" + dummyEntity.getId();
    }


    @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteDummyEntity(Model model, @PathVariable int id) {
        try {
            dao.deleteDummyEntityById(id);
            model.addAttribute("deletedDummyEntityId", id);
            return "dummyentities/delete";
        }catch (DummyEntityNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
        }catch (DummyEntityWriteException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}

class DummyEntityControllerIntegratedTest extends MvcThymeleafApplicationTests {


    @Test
    void createAddsOne() throws Exception {
        DummyEntity dummyEntity = new DummyEntity(0, "DE-13", "dek13", "dev13", 10, 20, 30);
        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/dummy-entities/add")
                .param("name", "DE-13")
                .param("key", "dek13")
                .param("value", "dev13")
                .param("x", Integer.valueOf(10).toString())
                .param("y", Integer.valueOf(20).toString())
                .param("z", Integer.valueOf(30).toString())
        ).andExpect(result -> assertEquals(302, result.getResponse().getStatus()));
    }

    @Test
    void createRedirectsToDehome () throws Exception {
        DummyEntity dummyEntity = new DummyEntity(0, "DE-13", "dek13", "dev13", 10, 20, 30);
        Map<String, Object> model = mockMvc.perform(
             MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/dummy-entities/add")
                .param("name", "DE-13")
                .param("key", "dek13")
                .param("value", "dev13")
                .param("x", Integer.valueOf(10).toString())
                .param("y", Integer.valueOf(20).toString())
                .param("z", Integer.valueOf(30).toString())
        ).andReturn().getModelAndView().getModel();

        DummyEntity newDummyEntity = (DummyEntity) model.get("dummyEntity");
        assertNotNull(newDummyEntity);
    }



}

It works perfectly in the browser but the second test is failing.
The way I see it, it is being redirected, which means the client should be making a request again to the end point that gets the new id and it should be returning this ?
I did not try with RedirectAttributes, as I am not sure its necessary, if this simulates a new request then when it hits the controller end point, everything should flow as normal ?
I tried to debug, it but I found out that the redirected end point never gets called during test, but I assume its working because the end result in the browser is perfect, it just does not work in these tests, Why is this ?
I would appreciate any help

@Test
void createRedirectsToDehome () throws Exception {
    //POST request triggers the redirect
    mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/dummy-entities/add")
            .param("name", "DE-13")
            .param("key", "dek13")
            .param("value", "dev13")
            .param("x", Integer.valueOf(10).toString())
            .param("y", Integer.valueOf(20).toString())
            .param("z", Integer.valueOf(30).toString())
    )
    // Assert/check response - 302 redirect
    .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
    
    // Capture the target URL
    .andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern("/dummy-entities/*"))
    
    //follow redirect manually by using get req
    .andDo(result -> {
        String redirectUrl = result.getResponse().getRedirectedUrl();
            // Perform GET on redirected URL
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(redirectUrl))
            // Expected 200 OK from redirected URL
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            // expected view name
            .andExpect(view().name("dummyentities/dummy-entity")); 
    });
}

is3xxRedirection():
This matcher checks if the response status code is within the 3xx range (300-399), which includes:
302 (Found),
303 (See Other),
301 (Moved Permanently),
307 (Temporary Redirect),
308 (Permanent Redirect), etc.
use andDo() to perform additional actions //following the redirect manually
U can follow by extracting the redirected Url and perform Get request then ensure the status code 200 and view rendered matches providing
.view().name()

Thank you This worked well for me, but in terms of truly understanding, it was so simple, I dont know why it took a week to figure this out, I did answer it as well

If you could please please answer this by any change I would be so grateful: stackoverflow.com/q/79093586/21505152, Thank you

Naren's answer above is great, and it shows how to test the redirects. But in terms of truly understanding how redirects work and why it was not working is as straight forward as I thought, but can't explain why I took so long to figure it out.
It's really simple, when a server sends a redirect response, it sends it to the client, the client gets a status code that shows it is a redirect response, with a url end point for the redirect.
The web browser automatically makes a second request to that redirected url sent by the server
But since, there is no web browser here, MockMvc cannot automatically make another request, this needs to be done manually, so no, there is no way to automatically have the redirect response happen.
I will need to make the second request, ideally with the .andDo method as already shown in the accepted answer

Yes, MockMvc is a simple and lightweight way to simulate HTTP requests so it will return the redirect response without following it.
sample usual test ends like below
public class RedirectControllerTest {     @Autowired     private MockMvc mockMvc;     @Test     public void shouldRedirectToAnotherPage() throws Exception {         mockMvc.perform(get("/originalPage"))                 .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())                 .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/redirectedPage"));     } }
if u want to verify what happens after, u need to send a seperate request to follow.
